# How to check if $H$ is a base for $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am having trouble trying to solve this exercise and I do not know how to do it :

[image]

I put the vectors of the basis in a matrix by columns, but I honestly do not know how to continue. I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the conditions $a_0-a_2+a_3=0$ and $a_0+a_1+a_2+a_3=0$, we can eliminate two of the $a_i$. We can write $a_2=a_0+a_3$ and 
$a_1=-a_0-a_2-a_3=-2a_0-2a_3$.

For any polynomial $f\in U$, we can write
$$\begin{aligned}
f(x)&=a_0-2(a_0+a_3)x+(a_0+a_3)x^2+a_3x^3\\
&=a_0(1-2x+x^2)+a_3(-2x+x^2+x^3)\\
\end{aligned}$$
$1-2x+x^2$ and $-2x+x^2+x^3$ therefore span $U$. It is also clear that they are linearly independent. Therefore, $\{1-2x+x^2,-2x+x^2+x^3\}$ is a basis for $U$.